# Here Maps iOS SDK Map Markers not visible on the map

Tags: ios

I have created `NMAMapView` object using storyboard and I am using the reference of that `NMAMapView` object in view controller code and added markers to it. In this case, the markers are visible on the screen

To set the zoom automatically I created `NMABoundingBox`, added markers to it and then set the bounding box to `NMAMapView` using `setBoundingBox::withAnimation` method.

But if I create the `NMAPMapView` object dynamically, set the view controller view frame to the `NMAMapView` and add it as a subview to view controller view and then added the markers to the view, then the markers are visible out of the map. I have to do a manual zoom out on the map to see the markers.

I have also tried using `setBoundingBox::insideRect::withAnimation` method of `NMAMapView` for the above dynamically created map scenario to set the zoom automatically. But the maps is being pointed to some random portion of the world with some inappropriate zoom.

Need resolution for this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I see a marker on the map only if some image is set as an `icon` of `NMAMapMarker`. Looks like there's no default marker available.

```
let coordinates: NMAGeoCoordinates = ...
let image: UIImage = ...
let marker = NMAMapMarker(geoCoordinates: coordinates, image: image)
```

or

```
let coordinates: NMAGeoCoordinates = ...
let marker = NMAMapMarker(geoCoordinates: coordinates)
let image: UIImage = ...
marker.icon = NMAImage(uiImage: image)
```

Hopefully, it helps.